# Program is only running if and not else if/else

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am new to C++, and I am struggling with if/else if statements. The program is a calculator that performs basic addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. The user gives 2 numbers and an operation, and the operation is used as an indicator of what to do with the two previous number inputs. The code is below.

````
```#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Get User Inputs
    int UserInput1, UserInput2, Output;
    string Calculation;
    cout << "Input first number ";
    cin >> UserInput1;
    cout << "\n\nInput Second Number ";
    cin >> UserInput2;
    cout << "\n\nAdd, Subtract, Multiply or Divide? ";
    cin >> Calculation;
    cout << "\n\n";


    if (Calculation == "Add" or "add") { //Performs addition
        Output = UserInput1 + UserInput2;
        cout << UserInput1 << " + " << UserInput2 << " = " << Output;
    } else if (Calculation == "Subtract" or "subtract") { //Performs subtraction
        Output = UserInput1 - UserInput2;
        cout << UserInput1 << " - " << UserInput2 << " = " << Output;
    } else if (Calculation == "Multiply" or "multiply") { //Performs multiplication
        Output = UserInput1 * UserInput2;
        cout << UserInput1 << " * " << UserInput2 << " = " << Output;
    } else if (Calculation == "Divide" or "divide") { //Performs division
        Output = UserInput1 / UserInput2;
        cout << UserInput1 << " / " << UserInput2 << " = " << Output;
    } else {
        cout << "Error";
    }
}```
````

When the program runs, it asks for the inputs as expected, but no matter what you enter, it will run the if statement only. Below is the output.

```
Input first number 5


Input Second Number 5


Add, Subtract, Multiply or Divide? multiply


5 + 5 = 10
```

Any suggestions on how I can get the program to include the else ifs/else? Any help is appriciated

Comment: You may want to learn the switch statement in c++

Comment: `Calculation == "Add" or "add"` is always true … `Calculation == "Add" or Calculation == "add"` is what you want. Although, I'd recommend moving away from the `and` `or` (etc) macros and using the operators `&&` and `||`

Comment: @ChrisMM -- in C++, `and` and `or` are not macros; they're "alternative tokens", and they act just like the tokens that they are alternatives for. In C they're macros. Either way, I don't like them. <g>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing 'or' in if statement with operator ||.

Ie. if (Calculation == "Add" || Calculation == "add") {...

http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/

Comment: This should help, but not because of replacing `or` -> `||`. The solution comes by oring to boolean expressions, which resolves the problem OP has because of programming like "spoken English". I must admit that I am unhappy with a working code proposal accompanied by a misleading (practically wrong) explanation. Thank you very much for explaining (I really do not like code-only answers...), but please explain better.

Comment: This has worked, thank you very much

Comment: William, what do you believe is the part of the code proposal which actually solves your problem? To understand what I mean, please try these two and find out which helps and which does not help: `(Calculation == "Add" or Calculation == "add")` and `(Calculation == "Add" ||  "add")`.

Comment: Yunnosch, ```(Calculation == "Add" || "add")``` helped, my issue was that I had not written the conditional statements properly, my original code was ```(Calculation == "Add" or "add")```. A small beginner error.

Answer (score 0):

After replacing the "or" with [the || operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/), the first if condition is `if (Calculation == "Add" || "add") {`

Logically what happens is `Calculation == "Add"` is tested first, which is false. Then, `"add"` is tested. But `"add"` is always true, because its value is not 0. You aren't comparing it to `Calculation`. And so the `if` is true and your path goes down the addition branch.

As already written, you can fix this using

```
if (Calculation == "Add" || Calculation == "add") {...
```

and similar for the other conditions.